# Alexa Skills - Maintain session in the simulator

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to maintain a session in the simulator so that I can chain intents and not have to start each sentences with "tell my skill {something}".
Each time i trigger an Intent, I can see in the output JSON that the session.new is always true.

What do I do wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you send responses, you use a "ask" response instead of a "tell" response.  A tell response will close the session.

With the Java SDK, you can create an ask response with:

```
SpeechletResponse.newAskResponse(speech, reprompt, card);
```

Whereas the tell response is created with:

```
SpeechletResponse.newTellResponse(speech, card);
```

Comment: I finally used a 'custom' payload and I return shouldEndSession; false in the response node.

Answer (score 1):

In node.js I realized that you do need the "repompt" part to keep the session attributes :

```
handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(speechText)
                .reprompt(speechText)
                .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
                .getResponse();
```

Comment: if you look at the sample node fact example index.js it has  

  // Uncomment the next line if you want to keep the session open so you can
      // ask for another fact without first re-opening the skill
      // .reprompt(requestAttributes.t('HELP_REPROMPT')